# Fetched data is not updated after changes on next js ssr page

Tags: javascript, next.js, server-side-rendering

I've got this kind of situation. My application has two pages. The main one is used to show statistics about the user's account. And the user can go to the second one to change these statistics. Both of these pages are server side rendered. So when I go to the first page I see my statistics fetched from the database. I go to the second one and change the data. Then I go back. To go back I use  component from "next/link". And here I am on the first page and I see the initial statistics. It seems like the page memoizing fetched data and doesn't update it when I go back. So what do I do to update the data every time the user goes to the statistics page? It looks like there's no other option except to make it a client component and use useEffect(() => {}, []) hook. What do you think?

Here's the statistics page:

```javascript
import Sidebar from "@/components/sidebar/component"
import Header from "@/components/header/component"
import StatisticsBoard from "@/components/statisticsBoard/component"
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth"
import { authOptions } from "@/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route"
import { redirect } from "next/navigation"

export default async function Home()
{
    const session = await getServerSession(authOptions)
    if(!session) redirect("/")
    let loadedAllocations = (await (await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/getAllocations", {

        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify({  userId: session.user.id })

    })).json()).allocations

    const loadedAllocaitonsGroups = (await (await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/getAllocationsGroups", {

        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify({  userId: session.user.id })

    })).json()).allocationsGroups

    const loadedLedgerEntries = (await (await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/getLedgerEntries", {

        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify({  userId: session.user.id, orderBy: { date: "asc" } })

    })).json()).ledgerEntries

    const loadedCategories = (await (await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/getCategories", {

        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify({  userId: session.user.id })

    })).json()).categories

    let allocationsGroupsMap = {}

    for(const groupData of loadedAllocaitonsGroups) {

        if(!allocationsGroupsMap[groupData.id]) allocationsGroupsMap[groupData.id] = {}
        allocationsGroupsMap[groupData.id] = { name: groupData.name, allocationsData: [] }
    }

    for (const allocationData of loadedAllocations) {

        if (!allocationData.allocationsGroupId) continue
        allocationsGroupsMap[allocationData.allocationsGroupId].allocationsData.push(allocationData)
    }

    loadedAllocations = loadedAllocations.filter((value) => !value.allocationsGroupId)

    let incomesCategoriesMap = {}
    let costsCategoriesMap = {}
    let total = 0
    let statistics = []

    for(const category of loadedCategories) {
        
        if(category.type[0] == 'I') incomesCategoriesMap[category.id] = { name: category.name, total: 0 }
        else costsCategoriesMap[category.id] = { name: category.name, total: 0 }
    }

    for(let i = 0; i < loadedLedgerEntries.length; i++) {

        if(incomesCategoriesMap.hasOwnProperty(loadedLedgerEntries[i].categoryId)) {

            incomesCategoriesMap[loadedLedgerEntries[i].categoryId].total += loadedLedgerEntries[i].amount
            total += loadedLedgerEntries[i].amount
        }

        else {
            
        costsCategoriesMap[loadedLedgerEntries[i].categoryId].total += loadedLedgerEntries[i].amount
            total -= loadedLedgerEntries[i].amount
        }

        statistics.push({ date: loadedLedgerEntries[i].date, money: total  })
    }

    console.log("rendering server page...");

    return (

        <div className="top-0 left-0 flex flex-row h-screen" 
            style={{ backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)", backgroundBlendMode: "multiply" }}>
            <Sidebar session={ session } loadedAllocations={ loadedAllocations } loadedAllocationsGroups={ Object.values(allocationsGroupsMap) }/>
            <div className="w-full m-3 flex flex-col">
                <Header session={ session } />
                <StatisticsBoard statistics={ statistics } incomesCategoriesMap={ incomesCategoriesMap} costsCategoriesMap={ costsCategoriesMap }/>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Do you have code samples for the two pages? By `server sider rendered` do you mean they fetch the data with `getServerSideProps`? My understanding is that requests made via GSSP will only be cached if the cache-control headers are configured to do so.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the App router, but as you're using server components (correct me if I'm wrong here), then it looks like your requests are being cached by Next.js automatically ([source](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating#caching-data)).

It looks as though you can invalidate the cache manually (for example, when you update the statistics on the second page, you could call the invalidation API if the update was successful). In that case, when you next view the first page, the query will be executed again. [Here is the documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating#on-demand-revalidation) for on-demand invalidation, and it looks as though the [revalidatePath API](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/revalidatePath) is what you want to use.

Good luck!

### Update with working CodeSandbox:

After playing around with the Next.js app router and trying to invalidate / revalidate the cache, I have a working example of what you want to achieve [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/sweet-tree-csm2wt).

A few things to note:

1. You need to activate experimental server actions in your `next.config.js` for the example to work. You will then need to restart the server.
2. You cannot revalidate API routes within the `/pages` directory this way - it will only work for routes at `/app/my-route/route.js`, for example.
3. `revalidatePath` doesn't seem to respect its argument (or I don't understand it fully). Only when I passed in `"/"` did it invalidate the server component cache. I fear this could cause everything within the `/app` directory to be invalidated.
4. If you run into issues doing this locally, you may need to remove the `.next` folder to clear the cache entirely.

Obviously, with the example above, you will need to adjust it to fit your exact needs and APIs, but I was able to get the cached API response to display every time until I invalidated the cache. The API then served a new response on the next page visit.

Comment: So the server caches the users' statistics. Then i wonder if one user would have some other user's statistics with this approach.

Comment: I presume not, as you would be using a different body / options for requests for different users. Next.js considers that case with its [Request Memoisation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching#request-memoization), so I would expect that the cache behaves similarly.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'll make some research though and maybe mark this answer as the solution.

Comment: No... I should say that after some more tests, I see that the data is updated only when the page is refreshed.

Comment: I guess the full application is sent to the user at the request time, so the data can be updated only on the client side.

Comment: Hmm, do you mean that it doesn't display the latest data when you simply navigate back to the page? I suppose the page could also be cached on the client, although I would expect that to be handled by Next.js. If yes, is it the same if you use a `next/link` instead of navigating using the back button?

Comment: Another thought: are you expecting to receive real-time updates, ie. like with websockets, which would update without any page navigation / refresh?

Comment: No, I don't expect data to update automatically while still on the same page. I handle this with states. I just expect data to be refreshed when I navigate to pages with <Link />

Comment: Okay, was just checking.
I've had a play around with the app router and managed to get the invalidation to work. I'll update my answer with some code samples and a CodeSandbox.

Comment: No problem, I've been meaning to look more into the app router as I'm still building with the pages directory only.
Did you manage to get it to work in your project?

Comment: No, I guess it's not possible. So I just fetch the data with the useEffect hook when the component is mounted. I finished the project and uploaded it to GitHub btw. https://github.com/MindW1n/Robofinancier-Next-js